# calculating on sum value at different table

Tags: mysql, sql

**This my code :**

```
SELECT barang.id_brg, barang.nm_brg, jen_sat, nm_kat, SUM( IFNULL(  stok_brg.stok, 0 ) ) AS stok, IFNULL( laku, 0 ) AS laku
        FROM barang
        JOIN satuan ON barang.id_sat = satuan.id_sat
        JOIN kategori ON barang.id_kat = kategori.id_kat
        LEFT JOIN stok_brg ON barang.id_brg = stok_brg.id_brg
        LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT barang.id_brg, SUM( IFNULL( brg_laku.dibeli, 0 ) ) AS laku
        FROM barang, brg_laku
        WHERE barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
        GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC
        ) AS brg_laku ON barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
        GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC
```

**Preview Of My Code:**

[image: this preview of my code]

the question is I want to make column stok - laku and make that result as column result can u guys get it sorry I was bad for my english so I don't know how to speak hope you guys can understand me Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want the difference between column `stok` and `laku`. If so try this:

```
select a.id_brg, a.nm_brg, a.jen_sat, a.nm_kat,a.stok,a.laku, (a.stok-a.laku) as difference
from (SELECT barang.id_brg, barang.nm_brg, jen_sat, nm_kat, SUM( IFNULL(  stok_brg.stok, 0 ) ) AS stok, IFNULL( laku, 0 ) AS laku
    FROM barang
    JOIN satuan ON barang.id_sat = satuan.id_sat
    JOIN kategori ON barang.id_kat = kategori.id_kat
    LEFT JOIN stok_brg ON barang.id_brg = stok_brg.id_brg
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT barang.id_brg, SUM( IFNULL( brg_laku.dibeli, 0 ) ) AS laku
    FROM barang, brg_laku
    WHERE barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
    GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC
    ) AS brg_laku ON barang.id_brg = brg_laku.id_brg
    GROUP BY barang.id_brg ASC) as a;
```

Comment: thanks that was right
now i just need understanding that code

Comment: It's not that complicated at all. Much of this has been done on your query and on this query I just used your query's data as a alias table and used it's data like `stok` ,`laku` to subtract.

Comment: how I add the WHERE a.difference <=3

Comment: You can add that on last after `as a where difference <4`.

Comment: sql said : Unknown column 'difference' in 'where clause'